# Emulator 'redir' command unavailable... (?)

Tags: networking, android-emulator

I am trying to configure my emulator to connect to my WiFi as per [these instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking), however, I find that the "redir" command is not available. My emulator is for API version 29, and its image was generated from the AVD manager supplied with version 4.0.1 of Android Studio.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The console has to be authenticated first to unlock more commands on the [emulator console](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console), including `redir`**.

1. After connecting through `telnet`, it will prompt something like this:

   ```
   Android Console: Authentication required
   Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
   Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in
   'C:\Users\<user_name>\.emulator_console_auth_token'
   OK
   ```
2. Browse/open the said file, and note/copy the 16-characters authorization token
3. Then, enter `auth <auth_token>`
4. Afterward, `redir` and more commands will be unlocked (typing `help` will show the available commands)

Comment: That worked. I wasn't expecting the console to need further information, and hence it may have helped if the instructions were given in the guide I was following. Thanks for your help.